# python two dimensional recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, combinations

I have list pairs of keys and their possible values that are parsed from command line. eg:

`[('-a',['1','2','3']), ('-b',['1','2'])]`

my goal is to produce combinations as follows:

```
prefix -a=1 -b=1 suffix
prefix -a=1 -b=2 suffix
prefix -a=2 -b=1 suffix
prefix -a=2 -b=2 suffix
prefix -a=3 -b=1 suffix
prefix -a=3 -b=2 suffix
```

problem is, the list can be of any length and so does the values in the sub lists.

The possible solution would be using some kind of recursion, so far what I wrote doesn't give me what I want:

```
def runner(args, comd=""):
    for i in range(len(args)):
        op, vals = args[i]

        for val in vals:
            comd = op + "=" + val + " " + runner(args[1:], comd)

        if i == len(args) - 1:
            print ("prefix " + comd + " suffix")

    return comd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two list. Use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for doing that. For example:

```
>>> my_list = [('-a',['1','2','3']), ('-b',['1','2'])]
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(my_list[0][1], my_list[1][1]))
[('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]
```

It gives the `list` of all combinations of `tuple` from both list.

---

Now, coming to your problem, below is the sample code:

```
my_list = [('-a',['1','2','3']), ('-b',['1','2'])]
keys, value_list = zip(*my_list)
for item in product(*value_list):
    val_list = ['{}={}'.format(key, val) for key, val in zip(keys, item)]
    print 'prefix {} suffix'.format(' '.join(val_list))

# Output:
prefix -a=1 -b=1 suffix
prefix -a=1 -b=2 suffix
prefix -a=2 -b=1 suffix
prefix -a=2 -b=2 suffix
prefix -a=3 -b=1 suffix
prefix -a=3 -b=2 suffix
```

**Explanation:**

[`zip([iterable, ...])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) returns a *list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables. The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence*. For example, in above code:

```
>>> keys, value_list = zip(*my_list)  # zipping the unwrapped "my_list"
>>> keys  # value of keys
('-a', '-b')
>>> value_list  # value of values_list
(['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2'])
```

Then I am doing the *cartesian product* on `values_list` (as explained in the very beginning) and again doing `zip` on the `keys` and each `item` of the cartesian product.

Comment: Where are a and b? Also are you really going to manually index a dict with 1000000 key/value pairs?

Comment: Your code does not do what the OP's code is doing so whatever about a generic solution, you may want to give a correct solution or delete the answer.

Comment: Thank you @anonymous for the answer and detailed explanation.